# About the Ring of Differentiable Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let D denote the Ring of differentiable functions $f:R\rightarrow R$ (R is denoting the Real Numbers in the whole post).
Given is $I=\left\{ f\epsilon D:f(0)=f'(0)=0 \right\} $

I'd like to show that $I\lhd D$, that there is a surjective Homomorphism

$R[x]\rightarrow D/I$ and that $D/I\cong R[x]/({ x }^{ 2 })$

I already showed that I is an Ideal of D, but i don't understand how to conclude the Part with the surjective Homomorphism, the last part follows directly from the First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings, only thing which i didn't yet understand is why we can say I=$({ x }^{ 2 })$.

Edit: actually the last part follow from the surjective HM by showing $({ x }^{ 2 })$ is a maximal Ideal, and that it is equal to the Kernel (which is maximal too) so Kernel=$({ x }^{ 2 })$ rest now follow by the I.T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $p\in\mathbb R [x] $ can also be considered to be a differentiable function $p:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ (if you don't mind, I will call it $p $ as well), so let's map $p\mapsto p/I $ (to its own class).

To show that this mapping is surjective: take any differentiable function $f $, let $a=f (0), b=f'(0) $, choose $p=a+bx $ and then note $p (0)=a, p'(0)=b $ as well. So, we have $(f-p)(0)=(f-p)'(0)=0$ and it follows that $f-p\in I $, i.e. $f/I=p/I $.

To finish: what is the kernel of mapping $p\mapsto p/I $? In other words, which polynomials $p=a+bx+\sum_{i=2}^nc_ix^i $ are in $I $? As $p (0)=a,p'(0)=b $, we conclude those are exactly those (and only those) polynomials where $a=b=0$, i.e. those divisible by $x^2$. Thus the kernel is $(x^2) $.

Comment: can we always consider the elements of R[x] as differentiable or are there special cases(like zero Polynom)?. Thanks for your Help it solved my Problem

Comment: As I said, the polynomials "can be considered..."... I said that to simplify my notation. Otherwise, the polynomial $p\in\mathbb R [x] $ is a different object from a "polynomial function" that maps $\xi\mapsto p(\xi) $ for $\xi\in\mathbb R $. Such a function is, as we know, always differentiable.